# How to use an alternative for switch case with objects?

Tags: php, switch-statement

Let's say I have an object `Class` that has (OR NOT) one object `student` and a attribute `id`.

I want to make an case scenario where it will do something if:

- If there is **no** `student` in the `class`.
- (if there is a `student`) If the `name` of the student is "**Brian**"
- If the `id` of the `class` is **3602** (e.g.)
- others combinations of these tests

As you can see it looks a little like the switch statement, except that I am not using strings to test the cases, so I couldn't use switch.

There a way of using something practical like the switch case instead of multiple if?

**UPDATE**
I don't need to use switch, so I am open minded for any other suggestion you could have for a multiple testing case. I just think that if, elsif, elsif, .. etc, is a little confusing

Comment: It's not really a good fit for a switch statement anyway as you're evaluating many different properties of the object (rather than many variations on a single property).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
switch (true) {
    case $object->student === null:
        // do stuff
        break;
    case  $object->student->name === 'Brian':
        // do other stuff
        break;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: What is the point of this exactly? It's multiple `if` statements written with more code using a `switch`.

Comment: While effective, it might be better (depending on what specifically he's trying to accomplish) to have the null case logic as the default case.

Comment: `switch (true)` shows that `switch` isn't the right tool here. `switch` is for multiple comparisons on the same variable or expression.

Comment: @jeroen first of all I've answered directly to the question. Secondly it looks more clean than using `if` and `elseif` statements.

Comment: @simon `switch (true)` is widely used technique, for instance check out Symfony or Doctrine sources to ensure

Comment: @AndreyMischenko I know, CakePHP does this as well. In my opinion it's a misuse of `switch`. And I disagree regarding readability. I find `if`/`elseif` more readable than the construct above. But I guess that's personal taste.